# Reactstrap Modal window not showing

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

Reactstrap is not showing modal window, when I click on launch button it is fading the main page but not displaying the window.

Please help me to resolve this.

below are my code and package.json

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';

class Demoextends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
      modal: false
    };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  };
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>Launch</Button>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
            <Button onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Demo
```

Below is package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-calendar": "^2.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import bootstrap in your app. [Installation - reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Comment: But it is changing my entire app css

Comment: yes, because if you use reacstrap, you are building a bootstrap based app. If you are using reactstrap just for the modal, use instead https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal